# Where can I find the eclipse plugin for hadoop 1.0.4

Tags: eclipse, hadoop-plugins

Recently,I am studying Hadoop.I want to use eclipse to do some MapReduce Program with Hadoop.

The environment is :

Hadoop 1.0.4;

Eclipse 4.2.1;

But I can not find the eclipse plugin in Hadoop 1.0.4.

Can Anyone tell me where is the eclipse plugin ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why, but due to some reason they have removed the plugin from Hadoop installation folder. Instead you can find Eclipse Plugin source code with build.xml file in your "HADOOP_HOME//src/contrib/eclipse-plugin" directory. Try to pull it from there and build.