# Yahoo hadoop tutorial

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I am trying to follow the Yahoo hadoop tutorial:
      http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module3.html#vm

Everything is fine until I try to connect my Eclipse IDE to the hadoop server process according to the "Getting Started With Eclipse" section.  The short story is that my "map reduce location", my DFS Location keeps coming back with "Error:null".  My VM is running and I can ping it from my PC.  Hadoop server is running as I have run the Pi example.

My PC runs WindowsXP and there is no "hadoop.job.ugi" in the Advanced list for the hadoop location....What does "/hadoop/mapred/system" refer too.  There is no such directory in the hadoop installation that you install from the tutorial.  It seems like a pretty important directory from the name of the field.  I have gone into the advanced settings and switched any reference to my WinXP login (Ben) over to "hadoop-user".  It is easy to find in the VM  the folder locations that it is looking for like "/tmp/hadoop-hadoop-user/mapred/temp".

Am I right in thinking I can run eclipse on the WinXP environment and connect to the VMWare process via its IP address?  Isn't that the point of the article?  It does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read it right. The eclipse plugin for hadoop has lot of caveats and there are couple of things that are not well documented. See the second answer by Icn over [Installing Hadoop's Eclipse Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782042/installing-hadoops-eclipse-plugin). Hopefully that would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

"/hadoop/mapred/system" refers to the directories inside HDFS, so you don't see it from terminal using ls

I did see the "hadoop.job.ugi" in Advanced list, and succeed to connected to the VM following the instructions there.

are you using the recommended version of eclipse (3.3.1) ?